# Tips for debugging WiFi on the command line?

Tags: command-line, wifi

I am running `Ubuntu 13.10` on a Thnkpad X1 Carbon. My Wifi card is `Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]`
 I normally connect to open WiFi networks using the commands

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 connect <ESSID> <Frequency> <BSSID>
dhclient wlan0
```

This method works for me everywhere except in one room on my campus, where the signal is very strong (`iwlist` reports a signal strength of under `-30dB`. I am fairly certain there is nothing wrong with the Access Point, because my phone connects to it just fine.

However, when I do the first command above, I am never able to associate with the Access Point, and `dmesg` always shows a message containing something about `ipv6` and `Wifi not ready`.

I have tried various version of the `iwlwifi` driver but none of them are able to work for this Access Point.

I am wondering if anyone has suggestions for debugging, such as "turning down the radio power", "turning up the radio power", other obscure settings that can be set on WiFi cards that might help?

I am also interested in knowing what sorts of root causes this kind of problem might have, since my wireless card seems to be able to other networks and AP's just fine.

Comment: What about using [wpa_supplicant](http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/) in debug mode? It throws quite a few debug messages.

Comment: I am trying to connect to `open` networks. Does `wpa_supplicant` work for non-WPA networks?

Comment: Yes. See section "Managed Wireless Network (Wpa_supplicant)" of this [manual](http://www.vscom.de/download/multiio/OnRISC/Alekto+Alena/OnRISC_User_Manual.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `wpa_supplicant` to connect to open AP. Add following section to the `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
ap_scan=1

# no encryption
network={
ssid="TEST"
key_mgmt=NONE
}
```

You'll find more details in the sample [/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf](http://hostap.epitest.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf)

Comment: Will try this the next time I return to campus, probably Monday. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Amazingly, using `wpa_supplicant` to connect instead of the raw `iw` tool actually works. I have no idea why, but this answer addresses the root issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

To interactively debug WiFi connections from the command line you can use the [wpa_cli](https://linux.die.net/man/8/wpa_cli) command.  See [this example](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#Connecting_with_wpa_cli).